# Tika text extraction not working on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, azure-blob-storage, apache-tika

I'm trying to use Tika to extract text from a bunch of simple txt files stored on HDFS. I have the following code in my reducer, but surprisingly Tika does not return anything. It work fine in my local machine but as soon as I move everything to hadoop cluster, the result is empty.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration());            
Path pt = new Path(Configs.BLOBSTORAGEPREFIX+fileAdd);          
InputStream stream = fs.open(pt);           


 AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
 BodyContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler();
 Metadata metadata = new Metadata();   

 parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata);       


  spaceContentBuffer.append(handler.toString());
```

The last line append the extreaxted content to a StringBuilder, but it is always empty.

p.s. my hadoop cluster is Azure HDInsight so the HDFS is Blob Storage.

I also tried the following code

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();         
BodyContentHandler handler =  new BodyContentHandler();
Parser parser = new TXTParser();            
ParseContext con = new ParseContext();          
parser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, con);
```

and I got the following error message:
`Failed to detect the character encoding of a document`

Comment: Did you make sure you shipped all of the Apache Tika jars and their dependencies to your Hadoop nodes, and correctly put them on the classpath for your job?

Comment: yes, everythinbg look fine. I don't get any error message. The only problem is the parser returns nothing as the extracted content. Can there be something wrong with the encoding? because files are stored on the HDFS (Azure Blob Storage)?

Comment: Check that you have all the parsers registered (ask AutoDetectParser for the child parsers), and try just doing a stand-alone detect and check it gets the right type

Comment: can you explain more, I didn't quite get that.

Comment: I tried a different approach and got an error message, could you check my updated post it might help.

Comment: [AutoDetectParser](https://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/parser/AutoDetectParser.html) -> [getAllComponentParsers()](https://tika.apache.org/1.9/api/org/apache/tika/parser/CompositeParser.html#getAllComponentParsers%28%29) and something like [this detection example](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tika/trunk/tika-example/src/main/java/org/apache/tika/example/SimpleTypeDetector.java)

Comment: @Gagravarr I checked the registered parsers, and here is what I got:

Registered parsers: [org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser]
File Type: octet-stream

anything wrong in here?

Comment: I just noticed that everything stored on Azure Blob will have type octet-stream, no matter what type of file it is. How can I parse the files using Tika then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81336/discussion-between-h-z-and-gagravarr).

Comment: If the user does not specify Content-Type when uploading a blob, it will be set to “application/octet-stream” by default. However not sure if it really impacts Apache Tika or not.

Answer (score 0):

If the user does not specify Content-Type when uploading a blob, it will be set to “application/octet-stream” by default.